# Multiple Projects Visual Studio 2015 npm

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, npm, visual-studio-2015

I have one solution with 3 web projects, 2 of which I would like to use a `package.json` (names: 'Site' and 'SatelliteSite'). These are all ASP.NET 4 projects that I am retrofitting npm/gulp/bower into, which works fine for 1 project which is why I'm so confused by my issue.

When I save the `package.json` in either of the 2 projects, the Package Manager Log goes off and runs `npm install`. That's great, with one exception.

What it is actually running, despite picking up the changes in both `package.json` files is just the 'Site' package.json. Upon restarting Visual Studio, it's now picking up 'SatelliteSite' and running with that `package.json`, which is great as I now have my dependencies for gulp, but rubbish if I ever needed to update.

Unloading the SatelliteSite project doesn't work as when saving it within Site, it still loads the SatelliteSite `package.json`. It's almost like it "registers" the first `package.json` it sees (ie. SatelliteSite loads before Site so after restart that is loaded first) and ignores the others, whilst still tracking for changes.

I'm assuming this is a bug in Visual Studio - but perhaps I'm doing something wrong and wondering if anyone else has encountered also / has any workarounds?

**EDIT**: A bit more info, I renamed the `package.json` in SatelliteSite now to a different name, and saved Site's `package.json`. It throws this error, which shows VS is basically setting the working directory for npm based on the first `package.json` it comes across, regardless of project.

```
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\\\node\\node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Development\source\Cedita.Site\Cedita.SatelliteSite
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path C:\Development\source\Cedita.Site\Cedita.SatelliteSite\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
```

Comment: Have you tried to run in some way `npm update --save` to update the changes?

Comment: For a workaround just add a target BeforeBuild with npm install in the csproj and it will work no matter visual studio version or msbuild. it will restore all the missing packages before the build takes place:     <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
      <Exec Command="call npm install" />  </Target> And I just checked it with 2 web projects in the same solution in VS 2015 and it went fine

Comment: The RC didn't install npm globally, so nowhere that I tried to run npm from (including developer console) would actually work. It seems RTM does indeed PATH up npm so it can be ran like that - I haven't actually tested if it's still broken in RTM but will test and come back.

Comment: Thanks guys for your workarounds - it's fixed in RTM, thankfully! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pleased to confirm that this issue is resolved in Visual Studio 2015 RTM.

```
====Executing command 'npm install'====

npm WARN package.json SatelliteSite@0.0.0 No description

====npm command completed with exit code 0====


====Executing command 'npm install'====

npm WARN package.json Site@0.0.0 No description

====npm command completed with exit code 0====
```